# I need to make a data row which contains the most appear of occurences using 2 tables

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I need to make a query that provides me the most common values over columns,
the ones with the most occurrences.

For example:

```
Name   Grade     Gender
--------------------------
Jeff   100       Male
Daniel 100       Male
Linda   80       Female
Jeff    90       Male
```

The query will provide me a datarow with Name - Jeff Grade - 100 Gender - Male

The query I have by far is this:

```
SELECT
    PhonesTBL.OperatingSystem, PhonesTBL.Memory, 
    PhonesTBL.BatterySize, PhonesTBL.CameraQuality, PhonesTBL.Processor, 
    PhonesTBL.ScreenSize, PhonesTBL.PhoneType 
FROM  
    PhonesTBL 
INNER JOIN 
    HistoryTBL ON PhonesTBL.PhoneID = HistoryTBL.PhoneID 
WHERE 
    UserID = Uid 
GROUP BY
    OperatingSystem, Memory, BatterySize, CameraQuality, Processor, 
    ScreenSize, PhoneType 
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

but it returns just distinct of values I want.

Looking for help , Ohad

Comment: have you tried using Left join instead of Inner? because inner join don't picks data if not exists in another table but left does

Comment: 1 table is containing the phoneID and what user got it  and the other the more detailed phone settings

Comment: try to remove your where clause and see if you get problem from there then

Comment: im just saying, the table above is just an example for what i want the query to do, the main query i need will be based on the example query i wrote jeff(the most occurence name) 100 (the most occurence grade) Male (the most occurence Gender)

Comment: sorry but i can't really understand what is your question or what you wanna do

Comment: i have 2 tables, one contains UserID and PhoneID, the other contains PhoneID and detailed phone collumns like Operating System, Memory and so on, i need a query that returns me the phone collumn like operating system that gives me the most of this collumn that appear many times, i need that query to do the same thing on all the above collumns and order it so the first one will contain the most occurences values on the collumns

Comment: have you tried count? like `select COUNT(OS),field,field,field from Table inner join othTbl on ID=ID order by COUNT(OS)`

Comment: if ill do only count on os, it will bring me all the other common fields or only sorted by the os tho

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really make sense.  You have sample data that has nothing to do with your query.  Let me use the sample data.

In MS Access, this is most simply done by putting the *mode* (the statistical name for what you want) in separate rows:

```
(select top (1) "name" as which, name
 from t
 group by name
 order by count(*) desc, name
) union all
(select top (1) "grade" as which, grade
 from t
 group by grade
 order by count(*) desc, grade
) union all
(select top (1) "gender" as which, gender
 from t
 group by gender
 order by count(*) desc, gender
);
```

Comment: so all i should do is doing this for all of my requested collumns? and im sorry my question is little bit messy, i tried to show my issue in the best way, i wanted to show the main idea of the query

Comment: @OBZ . . . Yes.

Comment: Dear Gorden, It Returns that the first row looks like this: -------------------------------Which - Gender Value  Gender - Same Gender Value ----------------------------------------  Grade Value    Gender - Same Grade Value ---------------------------and i want it to give me Gender - Gender Value Grade - Grade Value